# How can I copy an SQL Server 2014 Express database to the same server without damaging original database

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I am running SQL Server 2014 Express on my laptop.

I would to know how to copy a database to the same SQL Server instance without damaging or overwriting the original database.

I want to keep the old database and use it for testing.

I have looked at the two previous posts below but cannot see a definitive answer.

[copy a database within SQL Server Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269450/copy-a-database-within-sql-server-express)

[Create copy of database in sql server 2012 express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22501841/create-copy-of-database-in-sql-server-2012-express)

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: The very first answer in both links tell you exactly what to do:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/4269477/334849 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/22502170/334849

Comment: If you backup your original database (which is part of the process anyway) then you can always restore it back over the original in case you screw up. Other than that I agree with LittleBobbyTables: those answers are all you need. Try it. Then ask a question if it doesn't work. Don't just say "they don't look definitive", because it really is as simple as that.

Comment: Thanks, point taken. I re-read the posts and followed the advice from the second reply in this post and it worked fine. i am concerned though that if i back up the new copy it will affect the original. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269450/copy-a-database-within-sql-server-express