# SQL-Server: The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to restore a SQL Server backup file for my database, but it is throwing an error as follow:

> The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing

My database in SQL Server 2008 and the backup file is in 2005.

What can be the problem?

Comment: The highly voted answer below is a sledgehammer to crack a nut. The problem is most likely that you haven't selected the "*Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)*" option in the *Restore > Options* window. I had this problem from command line using `WITH MOVE`, and was fixed by using `WITH REPLACE, MOVE`.

Comment: I have the same error with one of my databases, but only when SQL Server Agent is turned off. If I turn it on, there is no error and I can restore without issue. My BAK file only contains a single database, and that database name (and logical filenames) are unique on my server.

Answer (score 978):

I too came across this issue.

Solution :

- Don't create an empty database and restore the `.bak` file on to it.
- Use **'Restore Database'** option accessible by right clicking the "Databases" branch of the SQL Server Management Studio and provide the database name while
  providing the source to restore.
- Also change the file names at "Files" if the other database still exists. Otherwise you get "The file '...' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'yourFirstDb'".

Comment: +1 for "*Don't create an empty database and restore the .bak file on to it*"... yes, that solves it. (But why didn't I get this problem all the other times I did the same thing? And didn't we only start doing that pre-create in the first place as a workaround for some *other* inexplicable error message? :])

Comment: In Restore Database, I went to Files, Restore As, and put in unique filenames, as it still had the original names for the data and log files.

Comment: Also change the file names at "Files" if the other database still exists. Otherwise you get "The file '...' cannot be overwritten. It is being used by database 'yourFirstDb'".

Comment: On SQL Server 2014, in the files tab, for some reason the restore location was set to ...\MSSQL\dbname... by default.  I had to change to ...\MSSQL\DATA\dbname.... to get it to work.

Comment: Also, remember to uncheck the "Tail log backup" option in the "Options" pane, that was the problem for me

Comment: Solution works as of SQL Server Management Studio 18.2

Comment: Works for MS SQL Server 2017 on Linux with MS SQL Server Management Studio 18.1

Comment: I don't understand, what is "Don't create an empty database and restore the .bak file on to it."?

Comment: @Deqing that means you will not create an empty Db and then right-click on it to restore the backup file instead, what you will do just open your SQL right click on the root DataBase folder and then select RESTORE. In the restore window give a unique name of DB that you want it will create Db itself.

Comment: MSSQL doesn't seem to create the folders (for me anyway) so be sure to create target folders for data & logs first if you change the path (and set permissions appropriately, etc.). Thanks for the concise and helpful steps for cloning.

Answer (score 234):

Either:

1) Use `WITH REPLACE` while using the `RESTORE` command (if using the GUI, it is found under Options -> Overwrite the existing database (`WITH REPLACE`)).

2) `Delete` the older database which is conflicting and restore again using `RESTORE` command.

Check the [link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/09/27/sql-server-fix-error-3154-the-backup-set-holds-a-backup-of-a-database-other-than-the-existing-database/) for more details.

Comment: This technique allowed a 2008R2 database to be restored to a 2012 Server.

Answer (score 108):

First create a blank database of the same name. Then go for the restore option

Under **Options** on the left pane don't forget to select

- Overwrite the existing database
- Preserve the replication settings

[image]

That's it

Answer (score 70):

I was facing same problem and found the solution by doing this, using SSMS 2014

```
Just select the Option Overwrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE)
```

[image: Existing Database> Task> Restore> Database]

Answer (score 51):

This causes always due to version incompatibility.
follow these steps to solve:

Step 1: Create a database with your preferred name. (In our case AdventureWorks)

Step 2: Write click on the database and click on Tasks >> Restore >> Database…

[image]

Step 3: On the restore screen go to third selection of Options. Now select the checkbox “Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)”

[image]

Step 4: Click OK. It should successfully restore the database.

Note: When you restore a database WITH REPLACE it will overwrite the old database.

Comment: For me just the step 3 was enough

Comment: worked in SQL Server 15

Answer (score 48):

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE DATABASE db;
GO

CREATE DATABASE db2;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE db TO DISK = 'c:\temp\db.bak' WITH INIT, COMPRESSION;
GO

RESTORE DATABASE db2
  FROM DISK = 'c:\temp\db.bak'
  WITH REPLACE,
  MOVE 'db' TO 'c:\temp\db2.mdf',
  MOVE 'db_log' TO 'c:\temp\db2.ldf';
```

Answer (score 36):

Simple 3 steps:

1- Right click on database → Tasks → restore → Database

2- Check `Device` as source and locate **.bak** (or zipped .bak) file

3- In the left pane click on `options` and:

- **check** Overwrite the existing database.
- **uncheck** Take tail-log backup before restore
- **check** Close existing connection to destination database.

Other options are really optional (and important of course)!

Answer (score 27):

If you are using the script approach and have an error concerning the LDF and MDF files, **you can first query the the backup file** for the **logical names** (and other details) of files in the backup set, using the following:

```
-- Queries the backup file for the file list in backup set, where Type denotes 
-- type of file. Can be L,D,F or S
-- info: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql
RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\Temp\DB_backup.bak'
GO
```

You will get results similar to the following:

[image]

And then you can use those logical names in the queries:

```
    -- Script assumes you want MDF and LDF files restored on separate drives. Modify for your scenario
    RESTORE DATABASE DB 
    FROM DISK='C:\Temp\DB_backup.bak'
    WITH REPLACE,
      MOVE 'DB' TO 'E:\MSSQL\Data\DB.mdf', -- "DB" is the mdf logical name from query above
      MOVE 'DB_log' TO 'F:\MSSQL\Logs\DB.ldf'; -- "DB_log" is LDF logical name from query above
```

More info on `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` [can be found from the SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql).

Comment: I had the same issue in the question, and in my case the Db backup was from remote server and i had to create the same folder structure in my D drive that resembles the output of first query. Then the second query worked correctly and database was restored.

Answer (score 25):

Its because the `.mdf` and `.ldf` Files from the original `Db` were locate at maybe `c:\programFile\....` and this info is saved in the Backup!

If you create the same DB on a different SQL Server where the installation is on `c:\program Files (x86)\ ....` you can not restore as usually. You need to relocate the path for `.mdf` and `.ldf` Files.

Therefore:

- Create a empty DB on the new Server
- Right click on the empty Db > Tasks > Restore > Database > click Device select your `.bak` Files > Select Db to restore into
- click on Files at left side > Select "Relocate all Files to Folder"
- click Options on the left site > click on Overwrite

Done!
Hope it helps!

Answer (score 21):

I had ran into similar problem today. Tried all the above solutions but didn't worked. So posting my solution here.

> Don't forget to uncheck Tail-long Backup before restore

[image: Don't forget to uncheck Tail-long Backup before restore]

Hope it help others too!

Answer (score 12):

Also as important is to make sure that, your **database name matches** the data base name in the backup you are trying to restore. If it does not match, you will get the same error.

Comment: This seems to be especially true if you have multiple files/file groups and partitioned tables

Answer (score 11):

Before doing anything else,  confirm if your backup is Full or Differential.  If you're trying to create a new database out of a differential backup, no matter what you do you will encounter the error.

Comment: This was the issue i was experiencing, so thanks for this!!! (I didn't know that the backup file was actually a differential backup.). Here's how to check: 
"RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK = 'C:\myfile.bak'"
In the results, BackupType of 1 = Full backup. BackupType of 5 = Differential backup.

Answer (score 11):

> system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror:The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'Dbname' database

I have came across to find soultion

1. Don't Create a database with the same name or different database name !Important.
2. right click the database | Tasks > Restore > Database
3. Under "Source for restore" select "From Device"
4. Select .bak file
5. Select the check box for the database in the gridview below
6. To DataBase: "Here You can type New Database Name" (Ex:DemoDB)
7. Don't select the Existing Database From DropDownlist
8. Now Click on Ok Button ,it will create a new Databse and restore all data from your .bak file .

[you can get help from this link even](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-restore-northwind-database-in-sql-server-in-1-minute/)

Hope it will help to sort out your issue...

Comment: "Don't Create a database with the same name or different database name !Important." What do you mean?

Answer (score 5):

Same issue with me.The solution for me is:

1. Right click on the database.
2. Select tasks, select restore database.
3. Click options on the left hand side.
4. Check first option OverWrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE).
5. Go to General, select source and destination database.
6. Click OK, that's it

Answer (score 4):

I was just trying to solve this issue.

I'd tried everything from running as admin through to the suggestions found here and elsewhere; what solved it for me in the end was to check the "relocate files" option in the Files property tab.

Hopefully this helps somebody else.

Answer (score 4):

Some of you have highly over complicated this. I found this to be extremely simple.

1) Create a database with the same name as your .bak file database name !Important

2) right click the database | Tasks > Restore > Database

3) Under "Source for restore" select "From Device"

4) Select .bak file

5) Select the check box for the database in the gridview below

6) Under "Select a Page" on the right Select "Options"

7) Select the checkbox labeled "Preserve the replication settings(WITH KEEP_REPLICATION)

Now Go back to the General page and click OK to restore the database...That is it.

Comment: where is that "select a page"?

Answer (score 3):

I had to create new db on my local for testing & i had a back up from my prod. I created the db first and tried to run the BAK on top of the new db which produced this error for me. I deleted the db and restored it while sourcing the new db name in the restore screen itself. The db was automatically created on restore.

Answer (score 2):

I got work done through alternate way, using Generate scripts. That did work for me as Backup-Restore didn't help to resolve the issue due to same error.

Answer (score 2):

In the Options, change the "Restore As" file name to the new database mdf and ldf. It is referencing the source database .mdf and .ldf  files.

Answer (score 1):

You can restore to a new DB, verify the file name syntax, it ll be in the log file, for the new SQL version ll be a "_log" suffix

ad check the overwrite the existing database flag in option tab

Fabio

Answer (score 1):

This helped me to import the back-up file from the system drive

1. Create a database with the same name(preferably) as your .bak file database name
2. Right click the database > Tasks > Restore > Database
3. Under "Source for restore" select "From Device"
4. Select the .bak file selecting the path from the system
5. Select the check box for the database in the list box below
6. Under "Select a Page" on the right Select "Options"
7. Select the checkbox labeled "Preserve the replication settings(WITH KEEP_REPLICATION)
8. Select the checkbox for Overwrite the existing database(WITH REPLACE)
   Now Go back to the General page and click OK to restore the database...

Answer (score 0):

Im sure this problem is related to the files and folders permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to restore a production database to a staging database on the same server.

The only thing that worked in my case was restore to a new blank database. This worked great, did not try to overwrite production files (which it would if you just restore production backup file to existing staging database). Then delete old database and rename - the files will keep the new temp name but in my case that is fine.

(Or otherwise delete the staging database first and then you can restore to new database with same name as staging database)

Answer (score 0):

instead of click on **Restore Database** click on  **Restore File and Filegroups..**

thats work on my sql server

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but on PS. I leave it here in case someone is trying to do the same

```
Restore-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance "<your instance name>" -Database "<your db name>" -BackupFile "<backup file route>.bak" -ReplaceDatabase
```

remember to use `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Force` and import `import-module sqlps`. Don't forget to set back your Execution Policy back to restricted once you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Usually dealing with .bak files are coming with headaches, a more straight forward way is using sqldump files to transfer databases.

1. Generate script of current database you want to move or copy.
2. **Instead of entire database**, select All Tables.
3. From the option menu choose save as script, and click on advance button and set the following configs (I am suing MSSQL 2016):
   [image]
4. Now, where you want to import these data, create a new database, switch to this new database (I mean set it as default)
5. Finally run the script, all table and data will be imported.

Good Luck.

5. List item