# BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because there is no current database backup

Tags: sql-server

I tried to restore a database but this message showed. How do I restore this database?

> Restore of database 'farhangi_db' failed.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RelationalEngineTasks)
>   ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: BACKUP LOG cannot be performed because
>   there is no current database backup. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

Comment: Is this a differential backup?

Comment: @AmirrezaKeshavarz: what? (motavajeh nemisham manzuretuno)

Comment: I mean that what kind of backup are you going to restore? (transaction log backup/full backup/differential backup?)

Comment: It seems broken transaction log

Comment: Does your database exists? L

Comment: I do this : mydatabaseName -> right click -> tasks -> restore -> database -> DEVICE :  .... -> OK

Comment: can any body solve error 3154?      
Restore failed for Server 'S-PC'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
------------------------------
The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing 'farhangi_db' database.
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 3154)

Comment: "The backup set holds a backup of a database other than the existing" is caused when you are attempting to restore a database that contains existing file information. In the Restore|File view you need to change the log and data files point to non-existing files.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Originally, I created a database and then restored the backup file to my new empty database:

> Right click on Databases > Restore Database > General : Device: [the
>   path of back up file] → OK

**This was wrong**. I shouldn't have first created the database.

Now, instead, I do this:

> Right click on Databases > Restore Database > General : Device: [the
>   path of back up file] → OK

Comment: So there's nothing wrong with doing a create new and restore. It's not the most direct approach, but it's certainly not incorrect. As @Andrii-Horda mentioned below, you do need to [CAUTIOUSLY choose the "WITH REPLACE" option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#REPLACEoption) when doing this.

Answer (score 176):

Another cause of this issue is when the `Take tail-log backup before restore` "Options" setting is enabled.

On the "Options" tab, Disable/uncheck `Take tail-log backup before restore` before restoring to a database that doesn't yet exist.

Comment: AND check option "WITH REPLACE"

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio v 18.10. In my case, it shows a similar option as disabled under the Media Options tab:

Backup the tail of the log, and leave the database in restoring state

This option is permanently disabled and can not be edited in the current state. How can it be enabled?

Answer (score 67):

Please see **below image** and apply changes in SqlServer :

first **right click on Database** --> **Task** --> **Restore** --> **Select Backup File** -->
 **Finally Apply Change in Options Tab**.

[image: please apply changes in SqlServer]

Comment: In my case I do this and check the first checkbox "Overwrite the existing database (WITH REPLACE)" and works.

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure there is a new database.
2. Make sure you have access to your database (user, password etc).
3. Make sure there is a backup file with no error in it.

Answer (score 3):

In our case it was due to the Recovery Model on the primary database having been changed after we did the backup in preparation for setting up log shipping.

Ensuring the Recovery Model was set to **Full Recovery** *before* doing the backup and setting up log shipping resolved it for us.

Answer (score 3):

You can use following SQL to restore if you've already created database

```
RESTORE DATABASE [YourDB]
FROM DISK = 'C:\YourDB.bak'
WITH MOVE 'YourDB' TO 'C:\YourDB.mdf',
MOVE 'YourDB_Log' TO 'C:\YourDB.ldf', REPLACE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another cause for this is if you have the same database restored under a different name.
Delete the existing one and then restoring solved it for me.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Lol, why couldn't Microsoft SQL Server have just said "Dude, delete the existing database first before restoring!"

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my error on restoring to non-existing DB from SQL 2008 to SQL 2014 by putting a check mark on Relocating to the new SQL2014 folder location.

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the existing DB that i wanted to override with the backup and restored it from backup and it worked without the error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether the database backup file, you trying to restore, is coming from the same environment as you trying to restore it onto.

Remember that destination path of .mdf and .ldf files lives with the backup file itself.

If this is not a case, that means the backup file is coming from a different environment from your current hosting one, make sure that .mdf and .ldf file path is the same (exists) as on your machine, relocate these otherwise. 
(Mostly a case of restoring db in Docker image)

**The way how to do it:**
In Databases -> Restore database -> [Files] option -> (Check "Relocate all files to folder" - mostly default path is populated on your hosting environment already)

Answer (score 0):

In case the problem still exists go to Restoration Database page and Check "Restore all files to folder" in "Files" tab This might help

Answer (score 0):

In my case I am restoring a **SQL Server 2008 R2** Database to **SQL Server 2016**
After selecting the file in the General tab, you should go to the Options tab and do **2** things:

> 1. You must activate Overwrite existing database
> 2. You must deactivate end of record copy

Answer (score -1):

Simply you can use this method:

1. If you have a database with same name:
   `WIN+R` -> `services.msc` -> `SQL SERVER(MSSQLSERVER)` -> `Stop`
2. Go to your MySQL Data folder path and delete previews database files
3. Start sql service
4. Right click on database and select Restore database
5. in Files tab change Data file folder and Log file folder
6. Click on OK to restore your database

my problem was solved with this method
BY...

Answer (score -1):

Click Right Click On Your Database The Press tasks>Back Up  and take a back up from your database before restore your database i'm using this way to solve this Problem