# How can I create a new database from a backup of another database, keeping the original in tact?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server Express 2008, and I would like to create a completely new database using the backup of another database, but I don't want to overwrite the original database or change it's name. I have read this post: [Creating new database from a backup of another Database on the same server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299811/creating-new-database-from-a-backup-of-another-database-on-the-same-server) but have researched the suggestion and it appears to replace the original database which I don't want to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you restore the database you have the possibility to write a name, you are not forced to restore on an existing database. You can change the name of the file too....

If you have special rules, you can still create an empty database then restore your database on that empty one.

Comment: Thanks, it was the renaming the file bit that I was missing!