# How to ensure independency of a database copy in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, database, copy, ssms

There's an SQL server database `member` with existing backup files `.bak`. Using *Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)*, one of these `.bak` files is imported into the newly created database `backup_member` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299811/creating-new-database-from-a-backup-of-another-database-on-the-same-server). By this, `backup_member` is an older copy of `member` and their content is verifiably different.

However, queries from an external GUI-interface with the database connectivity *ODBC* in between returns data from `member` although all interfaces appear to be adjusted to `backup_member`.

Is it possible, that `backup_member` internally still has a connection to `member` which has to be cut during the copy process in *SSMS*?

How to verify that `backup_member` is independent from `member` without having to delete `member`?

Possibly there's a problem due to settings in *Server properties* > *Connection Properties*. The field for *Database* in category *Connection* is filled with "member". Does it mean, that any query on this Server is done for `member` and never for other databases like `backup_member`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they each show up in SSMS and as you put it:

> their content is verifiably different

I would be checking to make sure the ODBC connection you think the application is using is actually the ODBC connection it's using. There's no "internal connection" you should need to worry about. They're their own databases at this point.