# Run complex SQL scripts from memo (multi lines)

Tags: sql-server-2008, delphi, ado

I'm executing sql scripts while using ADO and MSSQL server . 
Under [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp/3830948#3830948) you will find an first example of a multi lines sql statement like :

```
 use master;
 go;
 EXEC sp_detach_db
     @dbname=N'DATABASENAME';
 go;
```

I copy these lines from a Tmemo to my TADOQuery.sql.text but fail as already the go statement is not recognized and I get a keyword error by the mssql server. 
Can I run the whole sript as one TQquery  or do I have th split my query into several pieces, separated by the semicolon and iterate through the whole text ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first your code is not valid (no ; after `GO`) and has to be like this

```sql
USE master;
GO
EXEC sp_detach_db
    @dbname=N'DATABASENAME';
GO
```

In fact `GO` is a delimiter used by MSSMS to separate the SQL-Statements.

If you want to use the same scripts as MSSMS do, you have to work on that like MSSMS.

1. Split the script into single parts by delimiter `GO`
2. Send every part to the Database

Answer (score 2):

You have to split every statement whithout sending `go`.
SQL-Server is not interpreting GO, this is done by MSSMS.