# Neverending restore of database

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL Server version 14.0 (SSMS v17.3) and I wanted to copy and paste (duplicate) database for testing purposes. I did what is explained here ([How can I clone an SQL Server database on the same server in SQL Server 2008 Express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp)) in the first answer (222 votes, version 2014). I managed to create duplicate called MYDB2, but main database MYDB become unavailable. In SSMS I can see:

> MYDB (Restoring...)

that never ends (system restart didn't help), and when I open this database I get this error:

> "The database MYDB is not accessible. (ObjectExplorer)".

How can I fix first database and what is possible reason of corruption? Thank you in advance!

Comment: It is possible that you missed step 8? That is critical.

Comment: Rather not. I have this file: C:\SQLData\MYDB2.mdf. This one also exists: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MYDB.mdf

Comment: Please try running this: `RESTORE DATABASE MYDB WITH RECOVERY`. I've had that happen before and the `WITH RECOVERY` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try running this: `RESTORE DATABASE MYDB WITH RECOVERY`. I've had that happen before and the `WITH RECOVERY` resolved the issue.