# Duplicating the tempdb database to a more permanent database

Tags: sql-server

I originally posted this question but it got [removed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67962289/duplicating-my-tempdb-to-a-more-permanent-database?noredirect=1#comment120125173_67962289) for being a duplicate. I will try to be more clear in my question here, since I run into different problems when trying the solutions suggested.

I have set up a database using the `tempdb` and now I would like to duplicate this data to store as a more permanent database. However, all options I have found online do not allow me to do this. For example, the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829271/how-can-i-clone-an-sql-server-database-on-the-same-server-in-sql-server-2008-exp) shows step by step how to duplicate/restore a database but I do not have the same options using the `tempdb`.

For example, my database setup looks like the following. I can right click on the `model` database as follows, and I have the option to restore the database.

[image]

However, when I do the same to the `tempdb` I don't have this same option.

[image]

So my question is, how can I make a backup of the `tempdb` to a more permanent database?

EDIT:

When I store the data into a new table, the tables obtain strange names, this does not occur when storing in the `tempdb` (i.e. some names are stored correctly, others obtain random character/number strings).

[image]

Comment: So what do you have in tempDB you need to keep permanently? What do you do currently on a server restart?

Comment: I just made the mistake of storing the data in the `tempdb` to begin with. I just want copy the whole db to another database and keep everything exactly as it is.

Comment: Surely you have your creation scripts still, so just rerun them on the correct database.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

It doesn't make sense to backup and restore the temporary database.  By definition, temporary tables are *temporary*.  They go away when the server goes down.

If you have tables that you want to backup and restore, then you don't want them to be temporary tables.  You probably need to fix your application so the use of temporary tables is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, I do realise saving in the `tempdb` was not the best solution now. However, I when I try to download, process and store the tables into a new database, the table names obtain random characters and it doesn't process correctly. The only option which seems to work for me is to store it in the `tempdb` and now I am left with having to save the `tempdb` as another db... - this was my first SQL db I set up so mistakes were made.

Comment: @user113156 . . . That cannot be the "only option".  Anywhere you define a temporary table, you can define a *real* table, put it into a database, and that database can be backed up and restored.

Comment: *"This is too long for a comment.

It doesn't make sense to backup and restore the temporary database. By definition, temporary tables are temporary. They go away when the server goes down.

If you have tables that you want to backup and restore, then you don't want them to be temporary tables. You probably need to fix your application so the use of temporary tables is appropriate."* Seems to fit in a comment fine.