# How to stop a restore of a database with Microsoft SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to stop or cancel or kill a restore of a database with Microsoft SQL Server 2005?
Can you give me the request or procedure

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In SSMS type `sp_who` to get a list of open SPIDs (session ID's).

Find the one that contains your Restore.  The command will be something like `RESTORE DATABASE`.

Use `kill XXX` where XXX is the SPID of that transaction.

Comment: I've got the following error `Only user processes can be killed.`

Answer (score 1):

Find this spid and kill them or rollback transaction. Use sp_who for search the spid of restore.

Comment: I did sp_who but the retore is not here, however the Management Studio Express say me Restoring...

Comment: I have the same issue as @Christophe

Comment: Maybe you are actually looking for the same answer as found in this thread (if DB says "Restoring" but restore process is completed) https://stackoverflow.com/a/521039/1095493