# SQL Server: Database stuck in “Restoring” state with PHP

Tags: sql-server, pdo, restore

I tried to backup my database following the instruction from [SQL Server: Database stuck in "Restoring" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520967/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state). but i have my database stuck in "Restoring" state. php code below:

```
$database = "container";
$uid = "sa";
$pwd = "12345" ; 

try {
      $conn = new PDO( "sqlsrv:Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=$database", 
          $uid, 
          $pwd
          //,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)
          ); 
  $conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); }
catch( PDOException $e ) {
  die( "Error connecting to SQL Server" ); }

echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";

$backfile = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\sql server bk' ;
echo "Connected to SQL Server\n";
$backfile = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\sql server bk'  ;

$query = "RESTORE DATABASE child_database FROM DISK = '$backfile' WITH  REPLACE, RECOVERY ";
$conn->exec($query);
```

After running this code I got my child_database stuck in restoring state.however I copy the sql command

```
RESTORE DATABASE child_database FROM DISK = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL.1\MSSQL\Backup\sql server bk' WITH  REPLACE, RECOVERY
```

and run in microsoft sql server management tool it works just fine.

I try to run add php code

```
$conn->exec("RESTORE DATABASE child_database WITH RECOVERY");
```

I got an exception.

please help.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The database cannot be recovered because the log was not restored.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mssql\restore.php:31 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mssql\restore.php(31): PDO->exec('RESTORE DATABAS...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\mssql\restore.php on line 31

Comment: I haven't written any PHP for a LONG time, can you just stick $backfile in a string like that?

Comment: yes. the code run perfect. It restored the database but left the database in restoring state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems have problem with PDO driver, this problem may be in the ODBC/SNAC layer on which the driver is built. But this database restoring works well with other drivers.
I tried with sqlsrv and mssql, they worked well.
For more detail, see [Restoring a SQL Server Database from PHP](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/07/01/restoring-a-sql-server-database-from-php.aspx)