# Yii backup/restore MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql-server, yii, database-backups, database-restore

I have a Yii console application (using Yii v1.1.14) and I am wanting to include database backup and restore command functionality.

For backup functionality, the code is as follows:

```
$backupDir = "C:\\mssql_backup\\backup.bak";

// Grab the db name from the config values
$dbName = $this->dbConfig['dbMainDatabaseName'];

$cmd = "USE [master] BACKUP DATABASE [$dbName] TO DISK = '$backupDir' WITH FORMAT";

$this->mssql->createCommand($cmd)->execute();
```

The command executes but the backup is never created. I am not sure where the command is wrong as it executes perfectly fine using SQL Server Management Studio.

For restore functionality, the code is as follows:

```
$backupDir = "C:\\mssql_backup\\backup.bak";

// Grab the db name from the config values
$dbName = $this->dbConfig['dbMainDatabaseName'];

$singleUserCmd = "USE [master] ALTER DATABASE [$dbName] SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
$restoreCmd = "USE [master] RESTORE DATABASE [$dbName] FROM DISK ='$backupDir' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY";

$this->mssql->createCommand($singleUserCmd)->execute();
$this->mssql->createCommand($restoreCmd)->execute();
```

The database appears to be restored however, stuck in the recovering state (which the `WITH RECOVERY` is supposed to handle). I've tried different variations of switching `RECOVERY` and `REPLACE` options and even split the commands into 2 commands to execute and the same result is seen. Again, the commands run as expected in SQL Server Management Studio.

It might be worth noting that I also have a command to drop a database:

```
$singleUserCmd = "USE [master] ALTER DATABASE [$name] SET single_user WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
$dropCmd = "USE [master] DROP DATABASE [$name]";

$this->mssql->createCommand($singleUserCmd)->execute();
$this->mssql->createCommand($dropCmd)->execute();
```

The drop database command works flawlessly using the same connection, user, etc. which makes me think it is probably not a permissions issue.

I'm not sure where to go from here and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with Yii, it's actually a known issue in the PDO Layer in PHP, see [SQL Server: Database stuck in “Restoring” state with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050799/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state-with-php)