# MSSQL database stuck in 'restoring" state with PHP

Tags: php, ssms, sql-server-2014

I can execute the following in SSMS and the database will be fully backed up and restored under a new DB name:

```
USE [master]; BACKUP DATABASE PW_TEMPLATE TO DISK=N'C:\PW_TEMPLATE\PW_TEMPLATE_full.bak'
USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE PW_TEST_0001 FROM DISK = N'C:\PW_TEMPLATE\PW_TEMPLATE_full.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE' TO 'H:\DATA\PW_TEST_0001.mdf', MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE_log' TO 'I:\LOGS\PW_TEST_0001_log.ldf'
```

If I use the same from within PHP, it stays stuck in "restoring" status.

What is the difference between doing it in SSMS or via PHP and how can I fix this issue?

I'm using:

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3) (KB4022619) - 12.0.6024.0 (X64) 
Sep  7 2018 01:37:51 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: ) (Hypervisor)
```

PHP Code:

```
public function actionDeployDatabase($db_name)
{
    $backup = "USE [master]; BACKUP DATABASE PW_TEMPLATE TO DISK=N'C:\PW_TEMPLATE\PW_TEMPLATE_full.bak'";
    echo $backup . PHP_EOL;
    \Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($backup)->execute();
    $restore = "USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE __DBNAME__ FROM DISK = N'C:\PW_TEMPLATE\PW_TEMPLATE_full.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE' TO 'H:\DATA\__DBNAME__.mdf', MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE_log' TO 'I:\LOGS\__DBNAME___log.ldf'";
    $restore = $this->str_replace2('__DBNAME__', $db_name, $restore, -1, $count);
    echo $restore . PHP_EOL;
    \Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($restore)->execute();
    echo "Done..." . PHP_EOL;
}

public function str_replace2($find, $replacement, $subject, $limit = -1, &$count = 0)
{
    $ptn = '/' . preg_quote($find, '/') . '/';
    return preg_replace($ptn, $replacement, $subject, $limit, $count);
}
```

}

Comment: I believe the problem is you need to consume all the results from the restore command (like SSMS does). Try somethting like: `$resultSet = \Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($restore)->query();$resultSet->readAll();$resultSet->nextResult();`. I don't do PHP so I can't provide a tested answer.

Comment: A similar [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64018598/backup-sql-server-database-using-php/64041766#64041766). A possible solution is the following approach: `$result = \Yii::$app->db2->createCommand($backup); $result->execute(); while ($result->pdoStatement->nextRowset() != null) {};`

Comment: And an additional question - what driver do you use to connect to SQL Server? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please give what this prints out `echo $restore . PHP_EOL;` by commenting out the `str_replace2()` on `$restore`?

```
$restore = "USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE __DBNAME__ FROM DISK = N'C:\PW_TEMPLATE\PW_TEMPLATE_full.bak' WITH REPLACE, RECOVERY, MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE' TO 'H:\DATA\__DBNAME__.mdf', MOVE 'PW_TEMPLATE_log' TO 'I:\LOGS\__DBNAME___log.ldf'";
```

This statement is using `__DBNAME__` in a static string. Do you wish to use `PW_TEST_0001` instead? If so then `$restore` needs to be dynamic.

Edit: This is a familiar issue with the PDO driver, the problem maybe in the internal drivers upon which the PDO is built. Changing the driver will help resolve the issue.

Comment: It prints out exactly what I posted above, the 2nd SQL command

Comment: @AndreasHinderberger Oh I apologize for that but this is a familiar issue with the PDO driver, the problem maybe in the internal drivers upon which the PDO is built. Could you please try a different driver?
Reference from some very old issues - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24190722/yii-backup-restore-mssql-database
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050799/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state-with-php

Comment: Thanks. I haven't come over this issue yet during my google search. Please make it an answer as changing the driver (on a windows server, drivers installed with webtools) resolves the issue.

Comment: @AndreasHinderberger does the edit looks good for an answer? is that what you were trying to say?

Comment: Thanks @Adi. Answer accepted and bounty awarded :D

Comment: I ended up scrapping the whole PHP part of the deployment framework and implemented everything into a Windows Service. Problem solved, so I won't have to worry about different IIS PHP setups down the road