# Failing to restore a SQL database from Snapshot.

Tags: sql, sql-server, snapshot

I am getting the following error. It keeps on displaying (restoring) for database however it is not able to restore it. Any explanations for it? It says that the database is not accessible.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520967/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state

Comment: what error message are you getting?