# database in restore state

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, restore

I tired to restore my database but I saw that I am restoring a wrong one, so I immediately kill the process. Unfortunately the database was in restoring state and is not accessible anymore.

Can anyone help me to return back to normal state?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [SQL Server: Database stuck in “Restoring” state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520967/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state) but if you restored with overwrite your unlikely to be able to return to the state prior to the aborted restore (without another restore)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server: Database stuck in "Restoring" state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520967/sql-server-database-stuck-in-restoring-state)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using the following query to return your database online

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
WITH RECOVERY
```

If it throws an exception so you need to restore from a latest backup

```
RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabase
FROM DISK = 'C:\MyDatabase.bak'
WITH REPLACE,RECOVERY
```