# SQL Server database stuck on "Restoring..."

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore

I wanted to restore an SQL Server database to a **new** database so I could take a look at what records are in the backup. I have looked at [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520967/database-stuck-in-restoring-state) restoring to the **same** database and that's not what I want.

The script finished running but the original database states "Restoring..." and is inaccessible. I used SSMS with the resultant script being:

```
USE [master]
RESTORE DATABASE [WeatherTempo] 
FROM  DISK = N'E:\Weather_backup_2023_09_15_000032_3924540.bak' 
WITH  FILE = 1,  
MOVE N'Weather' TO N'F:\WeatherTempo.mdf',  
MOVE N'Weather_log' TO N'F:\WeatherTempo_log.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5

GO
```

So now I look and this is what I see in SSMS

```
Weather (Restoring...)
WeatherTempo
```

This has been going on for about an hour now. Is this normal? Do I now need to do something else to bring the original back online? The source MDF is about 6GB and the LDF is about 30GB.

Comment: `RESTORE DATABASE [WeatherTempo]`, "Weather (Restoring...)". Those are two different databases.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem normal. You can use this manual query:

```
RESTORE DATABASE Weather WITH RECOVERY
```

It maybe helpful to set it to be single user if it is in use and preventing recovery process:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Weather SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
```

Return it back to multi-user after completing the recovery process:

```
USE master;
GO
ALTER DATABASE Weather SET MULTI_USER;
```

Comment: You 100% about that? It's not going to wipe out the primary database? You might want to explain what that command does. And OP, make sure you know what you are doing and can be responsible for the outcome. Don't just trust SO answers.

Comment: Yeah this will wipe out my current db. I dont want to do that. I want to restore the backup to a NEW db.

Comment: This is intended to fix db which stuck in "Restoring..." state, not wiping data. However, please investigate it yourself and be very cautious before proceeding. The 'WITH RECOVERY' option is the default behavior for finishing restore operation. Details: 1) https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/difference-between-restore-with-recovery-restore-with-norecovery  2) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/recover-a-database-without-restoring-data-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16 3) https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/fix-sql-server-database-recovery-mode/

Comment: OK so after reading articles on this issue I decided to try this solution https://www.ubackup.com/enterprise-backup/sql-database-stuck-in-restoring-0862.html#:~:text=in%20SSMS%20Restore-,1.,restore%20section%2C%20then%20click%20OK. and it worked. As far as the script equivalent, I'll post that tomorrow. So far it appears that everything is working as designed.

Comment: @sinDizzy and is your solution different to that in the linked duplicate?

Comment: In the end I do not think its the same solution. I had to restore the transaction log.